# Wrong fonts being printed

Tags: printing, printer, fonts, opentype

Im trying to print a simple document to an HP LaserJet P4015dn, but the fonts I need to use (Trajan Pro and Adobe Garamond) are being replaced by the printer.

I get the same results printing the document as a Word file or PDF.

[image: screen vs print]

*Screen (left) & print*

What does this problem mean and where does it likely originate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your printer driver sending the fonts to the printer?

Make sure your printer driver is correctly configured. It looks like the system is sending PCL or PostScript data to the printer and is failing to send the required fonts to render the document correctly. It's also possible the printer is set up to use only its onboard fonts, and therefore is refusing to use the fonts sent by the application or printer driver.

Try to send the raw data as a PostScript file. You can create it from the print dialog:
[image: Save as PostScript...]

More information: [Why do printers have resident fonts, and how do I use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/575282/why-do-printers-have-resident-fonts-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: It's hard to say because the drivers are [now installed through Apple Software Update](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03413323-7%257CdocLocale%253Den_US%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), but the print dialog does report accurate information about the printer. Including toner and wear levels.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and mentioning PostScript. I was able to save a new `.ps` file from the print dialog, and print that, which worked! Does this format embed the fonts? I guess that would mean my computer is not sending the fonts after all.

Comment: @Louis: If you sent the PostScript file as raw data directly to the printer and it works, than it looks like your printer driver is the culprit. Make sure it is set up not to use only the printer's onboard fonts.